# How to Count String in a Column

Tags: r, string

I am a novice in R and have a data with two fields. I need to count the number of times the first field element appears in the second field. The second field can contain more one element due to which the below code isn't giving the right answer. Please tell how to modify this or what function can I use here. The count for A1 should be 3 but it is coming as 1 since the presence of A1 in A1;A2 and A3;A1 are not recognized in this code. Thanks.

```
df0 <- data.frame (ID  = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "C1", "D1"),
                  Refer = c(" ", " ", "A1", "A1;A2", "A3;A1", "A2","A2;C1")
)

n1 <- nrow(df0)

df1 = data.frame(matrix(
  vector(), 0, 2, dimnames=list(c(), c("ID","Count"))),
  stringsAsFactors=F)

for (i in 1:n1){
  
  id <- df0$ID[i]
  df2 <- filter(df0, Refer == id) # This assumes only a single ID can be there in Refer
  n2 <- nrow(df2) 
  df1[i,1] <- id
  df1[i,2] <- n2

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might `strsplit` `"Refer"` at `;` and `unlist` it. Next create a `factor` out of it using `"Id"` as levels and simply `table` the result.

```
table(factor(unlist(strsplit(df0$Refer, ';')), levels=df0$ID))
# A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 C1 D1 
#  3  3  1  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, everyone, for your quick suggestions. These were really insightful!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Although, you should use `grepl()` instead of exact filtering `Refer == id`.

```
library(dplyr)
df0 <- data.frame (ID  = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "C1", "D1"),
                   Refer = c(" ", " ", "A1", "A1;A2", "A3;A1", "A2","A2;C1")
)


result <- lapply(df0$ID, function(x){
  n = df0 %>% filter(grepl(x, Refer)) %>% nrow
  data.frame(ID = x, count = n)
}) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df0 %>% 
  separate_rows(Refer) %>% 
  mutate(x = str_detect(Refer, pattern)) %>%
  filter(x == TRUE) %>% 
  count(Refer)
```

```
  Refer     n
  <chr> <int>
1 A1        3
2 A2        3
3 A3        1
4 C1        1
```